# ERROR: open:src: None-Zero Exit(1)

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, redux, visual-studio-code

I'm playing with a React/Redux app using Visual Studio Code and Express as my dev server.

Everything was working fine until I killed my terminal to run a new `npm start -s` command and started getting the following error. Anyone has any idea what this is about?

```
events.js:154                                                                                                                
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event                                                                                   
      ^                                                                                                                      

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000                                                                                             
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)                                                                       
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:916:20)                                                                       
    at Server.__dirname.Server.Server._listen2 (net.js:1246:14)                                                              
    at listen (net.js:1282:10)                                                                                               
    at Server.__dirname.Server.Server.listen (net.js:1378:5)                                                                 
    at EventEmitter.listen (C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio Code\ReactReduxGitHub\node_modules\express\lib\application.j
    at Object.<anonymous> (srcServer.js:24:5)                                                                                
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)                                                                                    
    at loader (C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio Code\ReactReduxGitHub\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:158:5)     
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio Code\ReactReduxGitHub\no
lib\node.js:168:7)                                                                                                           
ERROR: open:src: None-Zero Exit(1);
```

Comment: Look like your server instance was not closed when you closed the teminal. Try `pkill nodejs` or `pkill node` if on unix system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your server did not close properly you need to close the server manually. If you are on a unix system try

```
ps aux | grep node
```

to get the process ids.

and then:

```
kill -9 PID
```

`-9 on kill` sends a `SIGKILL`

If on windows you can try to Run `cmd.exe as 'Administrator':`

```
C:\Windows\System32>taskkill /F /IM node.exe
```